# Needing to access table from subquery in main update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in need of a way to access a column from the inner table from a subquery, which I have included below with database/table names changed. The inner query returns all of the Item_Ids of Items that have a specific term config and belong to a specific customer. Obviously, the SET currently doesn't work as I can't access any of the rows of `let` from the main query.

I'm fairly new to SQL and am struggling to wrap my head around how I might convert this to using joins instead of a subquery. The problem is that I need to be able to set ALL of the Grand Totals for any of the Item_Ids that come from the subquery.

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[Items]
    SET GrandTotal = GrandTotal / let.CurrentValue
    WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT let.Item_Id
            FROM [Database].[dbo].[ItemTerms] let
            WHERE TermConfig_Id = 'TERM_CONFIG_ID'
                AND Item_Id IN (
                    SELECT le2.Id
                    FROM [Database].[dbo].[LaneExhibits] le2
                    WHERE Customer_Id = 'CUST_ID'
                    )
            )
```

**EDIT: Add Sample Row from Subquery**

Columns are Id, DataValueStatus, CurrentValue, PreviousValue, Item_Id, TermConfig_Id. The subquery only returns the Item_Id but that is the rest of the data.

```
424C8BF4-0FCB-E711-80C9-005056BA0972    1   460 NULL    2D4C8BF4-0FCB-E711-80C9-005056BA0972    B8FCE730-27BE-E711-80C9-005056BA0972
```

Comment: Please include some sample data, before and after.

Comment: Sure, @TimBiegeleisen. One moment and I'll provide some of the sample data returned by the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner join version:

```
UPDATE i
SET GrandTotal = GrandTotal / let.CurrentValue
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Items] i
INNER JOIN [Database].[dbo].[ItemTerms] let ON i.Id=let.Item_Id
WHERE TermConfig_Id = 'TERM_CONFIG_ID'
    AND Item_Id IN (
        SELECT le2.Id
        FROM [Database].[dbo].[LaneExhibits] le2
        WHERE Customer_Id = 'CUST_ID'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Merge** is your friend https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

simplified sample from your example

```
MERGE [Database].[dbo].[Items] AS target  
    USING (SELECT let.Item_Id, let.CurrentValue FROM [Database].[dbo].[ItemTerms] let 
           /* other joins and filters here */
          ) AS source (Item_Id, CurrentValue)  
    ON (target.Item_Id = source.id /* or what you want */)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
   UPDATE SET GrandTotal = source.GrandTotal / source.CurrentValue
```